# mysql to mysqli expects parameter error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I dug up an old application I had developed in php ver. 4.***, mysql 4.*** so i restored it in Wamp, running php ver. 5.5. and mysql 5.6.**

However, what I am realizing is the old `mysql_query,mysql_select_db,mysql_connect` need to be changed to `mysqli_`.

I am getting the following errors:

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

and I am not exactly sure if I am to go through and change all `mysql_` to `mysqli_`

Comment: Make sure there are no instances of  `mysql_` anywhere; connection also. `mysqli_select_db()` needs to be something like `mysqli_select_db($con, $database)`

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii-You are pretty much saying change all mysql_ to mysqli_?

Comment: @dames Yes. `mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions do not mix together. However, `mysqli_` works differently than `mysql_` so you may have to do a few adjustments along the way, such as using `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for instance; it needs DB connection. I.e.: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variable)`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you alot, and for general question reviewers honestly the only dumb question is the question not asked so I am in a little shock to see my question being noted as not useful

Comment: No this is a learning area so please leave the comments and questions I was just stating, the answers were helpful to me and hopefully someone else in the future as stated Thanks again

Comment: @dames Ah ok and you're quite welcome. Sorry, I posted an answer below, but made an additional note about prepared statements. Let me know if you want me to delete it.

Comment: isn't `mysql_` deprecated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there are no instances of `mysql_` anywhere; connection also. [`mysqli_select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.select-db.php) needs to be something like `mysqli_select_db($con, $database)`

`mysql_` and `mysqli_` functions do not mix together.

*However*, [`mysqli_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) works differently than [`mysql_`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) so you may have to do a few adjustments along the way, such as using [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for instance; it needs DB connection.

I.e.: `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $variable)`

Since you're getting started into using `mysqli_` functions, look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *it's much safer.*